# iptables "Bad argument `MASQUERADE'"

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, iptables

I am trying to create an "evil twin" access point for myself in Kali Linux with VirtualBo. I'm trying to get my iPhone to connect and be rerouted to a fake "terms of service" page. Here is what I am doing so far

```
$apt=eth0
$wifi=wlan0
#when monitor mode is enabled, the enviroment varible will adapt the name wlan0mon


sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo systemctl start apache2
sudo ifconfig $wifi down
sudo ifconfig $wifi mode monitor
sudo ifconfig $wifi up
sudo airmon-ng check
sudo airmon-ng start $wifi
```

exit and reopen terminal for $wifi to adapt the name wlan0mon

```
sudo airodump-ng $wifi

sudo airbase-ng -a $gatewayBSSID -e $gatewayESSID -c $ch $wifi

sudo cp /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.et.conf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
#et.conf is the non-original.
sudo ifconfig at0 up
sudo ifconfig at0 192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo dhcpd -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf -pf /var/run/dhcpd.pid at0
sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart

sudo iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface $atp -j MASQUERADE
```

Now this is where I'm getting stuck. The output of my iptables command is

> Bad argument `MASQUERADE'

I can't imagine why. I fulfilled all the requirements. MASQUERADE is a real argument but it's just not being recognized. There is no further information so I have nothing to work with. I also know very little about iptable forwarding rules. I tried but I spent 2 hours trying to untangle TCP/IP structure and I know just as much now as when I started, which is very little. How can I further diagnose the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The error message mentions `MASQUERADE` but the root of your problem is `$atp`. There is a typo. Your command

```
sudo iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface $atp -j MASQUERADE
```

is really

```
sudo iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface -j MASQUERADE
```

because you define `$apt=eth0` but then you use unquoted `$atp` (not `$apt`, a typo!) which resolves to unquoted empty string and vanishes.

In effect `-j` is taken as an interface name, so `MASQUERADE` appears as standalone argument and doesn't behave as `-j MASQUERADE` would normally do.

If you followed a best practice to quote variables, `--out-interface "$atp"` would yield `Empty interface is likely to be undesired` which would bring your attention to the `"$atp"` argument where the real problem is. A quoted empty string generates an empty argument to the command (`iptables` in this case, putting `sudo` aside is justified here), so if empty string is unexpected, the command can react accordingly and this is good.

An unquoted empty string just vanishes. This "shifts" arguments that follow. Your `iptables` never knew there was something between `--out-interface` and `-j`. Command line parser gets fooled and the command may only complain about *another* argument, like `MASQUERADE` in your case. The alternative is worse: in general if these "shifted" arguments happen to build a proper continuation, the command will run with the array of options you never intended to pass to it. This may be bad; with `sudo` this may be very bad.

The lesson is: quote your variables.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I tried eth0 without the variable and it worked, but why? If i were to do a quoted “$apt” it just gives me the literal value which would be invalid.

Comment: @user21303 There's nothing to elaborate. A typo: `$atp` vs `$apt`.

Comment: Gotcha. I had a feeling that understanding the OSI model was a wild goose chase. The solution for people like me has always been something simple. Thanks man! Than being said, are there any good explanations on OSI for idiots like me? I’m genuinely curious

Comment: All the tutorials I have seen are waaaaaayyyy to advanced for ne. I’m sure it’s not hard, people just explaining it weird.

Comment: @user21303 I can't help you with OSI model, not my expertise. Here I just spotted a typo and applied my knowledge of shell behavior and of a generic procedure of parsing command line options like `-j`. This approach would work with almost any command experiencing a typo of this kind. I think this particular question is solved. If you'd like to ask for learning material recommendation in a *separate* question, please note this is off-topic here on Super User.